# Angular 2 Add or Remove item from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have this method here:

```js
messageSelected($event, index) {
  console.log($event.target.checked);
  console.log(index);
  if ($event.target.checked) {
    this.selectedMessages.push($event.target.getAttribute('name'));
  }
  else {
    var item = this.selectedMessages.indexOf($event.target.getAttribute('name'), 0);
    this.selectedMessages.slice(item, 1);
  }
  console.log(this.selectedMessages);
}
```

What I am trying to do is if an item is checked, add the item to the array (this part works) now I am trying to remove the item from the array if the checked is false (this part is not working)

The problem is that the item is not getting removed from the array. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let i of userMessages; let item = index">
  <div class="card-body row-eq-height clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-2 vertical-center text-center">
      <div class="avatar">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 vertical-center xs-center-text">
      <strong class="username">Username</strong>
      <p><a class="read-more" [routerLink]="['/singleMessage/' + i.id]">{{i.subject}}</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2  col-xs-6  clearfix">
      <span class="date">{{i.updated_at | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1  col-xs-6  text-right clearfix no-x-padding">
      <div class="custom-check pull-right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{i.id}}" name="{{i.id}}" (change)="messageSelected($event, item)"/>
        <label for="{{i.id}}"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, I think you meant to use `splice` instead of `slice`

Comment: Thanks, thats worked....if you want to put into an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the confusion between `slice` (not mutating option) and `splice`, it seems like you're using angular as vanilla js.

The whole idea of using a framework like this, is to get rid of DOM inspection / manipulation.

You don't need to overload the `<input name>`, you could call directly `messageSelected($event.target.checked, i.id)` (modifying the function firm as well, providing all the needed data).

Better than that, you could use two way binding `[(ngModel)]="selectedItems[i.id]"` to bind the `checkbox` to a map (object) of "selected items", and then simply extract the `true` entries, mapping this to an array.

Or, if you dont mind to mutate the `i` object, you could bind `ngModel` directly on a custom property like `[(ngModel)]="i.selected"`.

The idea is to avoid wiring manually the `change` and the `getAttribute('name')`.

Here's a living example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjxn1y84wm

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS binds to the Array Object, and the [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) function in JS creates a new array as a result, leaving the original array as it is.

You should use [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) (note the p) which will update the array.

For example:

```
var index = this.selectedMessages.indexOf($event.target.getAttribute('name'));
this.selectedMessages.splice(index, 1);
```